# JAVA to PHP httpClient POST and FILE request not working

Tags: java, php

Trying to send POST variable and a FILE , file is getting stored at location but I am not able to send post data.

```
  HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 2024 * 2024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    String appName = "basic";
        // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL("http://X.y.z.q/upload2.php");

        // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("file", fileName);
        conn.setRequestProperty("description", appName); ----->> trying to send appName 

        String description = appName;

        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());



        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\";filename=\""
                + appName + "\""+ lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\""
                + fileName + "\""+ lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {

            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        }

        //   send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
```

AT PHP Side

$description  =  $_POST["description"];

it says   description undefiened in logs.

What is wrong with my code

Comment: Looks like `boundary` is not set before being used in `conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);`. Are you sure you want it that way? Consider removing the boundary parameter altogether and let the default values take precedence? Also, out of curiosity, do you have access to PHP code, does it receive anything if variable name is changed from `description` to something else? Or if it's passed before the `file`?

Comment: Yes I have access to PHP code. and I have  boundary set. File is getting uploaded properly I just need to send a variable